# How to specify structured streaming time based window in straight Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

We are using structured streaming to perform aggregations on real time data.  I'm creating a configurable Spark job that is given a configuration and uses it to group rows across tumbling windows and performs aggregations.  I know how to do this with the functional interface.

Here is a code fragment using the functional interface

```
var valStream = sparkSession.sql(sparkSession.sql(config.aggSelect)) //<- 1
  .withWatermark("eventTime", "15 minutes")                          //<- 2
  .groupBy(window($"eventTime", "1 minute"), $"aggCol1", $"aggCol2") //<- 3
  .agg(count($"aggCol2").as("myAgg2Count"))
```

Line 1 executes a SQL string that comes from the configuration.  I would like to move lines 2 & 3 into the SQL syntax so that the grouping and aggregations are specified in the configuration.

Does anyone out there know how to specify this in Spark SQL?

Answer (score 1):

`withWatermark` does not have a corresponding SQL syntax. You have to use the dataframe API.

For aggregation, you can do something like

```
select count(aggcol2) as myAgg2Count
from xxx
group by window(eventTime, "1 minute"), aggCo1, aggCol2
```